# TensorFlow Slim - Clone on cpu

Tags: tensorflow

What does 'Use CPUs to deploy clones' mean in the following snippet (slim/train_image_classifier.py):

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean(
    'clone_on_cpu', False,
    'Use CPUs to deploy clones.'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use CPUs to deploy clones' mean

In general setup model losses and gradients are calculated on GPUs, a single clone use a single GPU. For multi GPUs training multiples clones are created. If you have 4 GPUs 4 clones are created and loss for separate batches are computed simultaneously (data parallelism). That said, Now if you don't have GPUs you can use multiple CPUs to for data parallelism ( will be slower than GPU off course). `USE CPUs to deploy clones` option let you use CPUs for data parallelism; to compute model losses and gradients on cpus.

Comment: Ok, so if one sets number of clones to 8 and clone on cpu to true, one would end up with 8 clones running on the CPU?